# Why is electron temperature in plasma higher than ion temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, plasma-physics

Wikipedia [states](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_temperature) that

> The electron temperature of a plasma can be several orders of magnitude higher than the temperature of the neutral species or of the ions. This is a result of two facts. Firstly, many plasma sources heat the electrons more strongly than the ions. **Secondly, atoms and ions are much heavier than electrons, and energy transfer in a two-body collision is much more efficient if the masses are similar**. Therefore, equilibration of the temperature happens very slowly, and is not achieved during the time range of the observation.

How can it be *less efficient* ? Is there energy loss? Where does the energy go if no new particles are produced?

Also, maybe unrelated, but is the temperature at equilibrium in stars?

Comment: As for efficiency, consider simple hard sphere scattering. A ball of mass $m$ hits another ball of mass $m$ - in a head on collision the first ball can transfer _all_ of its energy to the second ball. For a ball of mass $m/2000$ (an electron)  hitting a ball of mass $m$ (a proton), how much energy goes into the second ball? For heavier ions, it only gets worse.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143738/59023