# How to calculate the free mean path of electrons in the gas mixture?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory, scattering-cross-section, mean-free-path

How to calculate the free mean path of electrons in the gas mixture? I understand (a little bit) the mean free path concept for the atomic collisions but I am not sure what to do if I am interested in the electrons only. Is it different for a whole atom and a single electron?

The mean free path is generally defined as: $\lambda = \frac{1}{n\pi r^2}$ where $r$ is the diameter of the atom and $n$ is the number density of the particles.

I have seen so many different equations on the internet for the electron mean path but I am so confused, I really don't understand it. So any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You are talking about a gas where electrons bound to atoms or about plasma? In the former case the question doesn't make much sense or implies some very specific conditions (like additional electrons injected.)

Answer (score 0):

First you calculate the [Coulomb collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_collision) rates (e.g., see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268594/59023), $\nu_{ss'}$, then you take the rms thermal speed between the two colliding species, $V_{Tss'}$, and divide it by the collision rates to get the [mean free path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path), $\lambda_{s} = \frac{ V_{Tss'} }{ \nu_{ss'} }$, of species $s$ propagating through species $s'$.

Note this is all purely statistical.  That is, the collision rates are a statistical measure of the expected number of $90^{\circ}$ deflections a particle will experience per unit time.  It's not an exact value for every particle, it's just a statistical expectation.