# Can you have two different Bohm velocities within a multispecies plasma?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics, diffusion

How would you calculate 2 different [bohm velocities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohm_diffusion) in a multi species plasma, say H+ and N gas excited by a microwave reactor.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268594/59023

Comment: thanks, but I already know most of the theory on plasma physics. I came here to see if someone has found an answer to that question